# Netsuite and Scribe Online - Filtering

Tags: filter, netsuite, scribe-workbench

I am using Scribe Online as an integration service, facilitating the exchange of data between Netsuite and IBM Cloud (formerly SilverPop). In Scribe it's possible to filter the queries made to Netsuite and so narrow the data retrieved.

While I can set the filter to fetch records where e.g. 'internalid is greater than 100;' the condition where 'internalid is less than 100' is not supported; and using a date produces similar result. It seems that 'less than' is not supported and Scribe Support suggest this may be a limitation of Netsuite's API.

[image: Scribe Online Map - Query Filter]

[image: Scribe Online Map - Query Error]

How can I filter within a range of criteria e.g. a date range or a numerical range?

Does Netsuite's API limit this kind of filtering or are there ways to achieve it?

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with Scribe, but here is how this is accomplished within NetSuite itself.

To compare an Internal ID as a number, you need to use the field `internalidnumber` instead of `internalid`. `internalid` is a String, so the less than operator isn't applicable.

Dates use very different operators. Instead of less, for Dates you would use operators like `between`, `before`, `after`, `onorbefore`, `onorafter`. There is a NetSuite Help document titled *Search Operators* that enumerates all possible search operators and which types of fields they apply to.

Comment: It makes sense that trying to filter a range will not work with a string. Thank you erictgrubaugh. You are correct that internalID comes through into Scribe as a string. I don't have access to internalIDnumber in Scribe but can convert the string to integer32, which may allow more options will filtering.